# CS50 Caesar output comes as aaaaa

Tags: arrays, c, string, cs50, caesar-cipher

For some reason when I change the copy of string s that is (string c), string s also gets changed and for loop j keeps on looping until it reached position zero in string alphabet which is 'a'.

```
int key = atoi(keys);

    string s = get_string("plaintext: ");
    string c = s;

    int length = strlen(s);

    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    int position = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("Before Conversion: %c\n",s[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        {

            if(s[i] == alphabet[j])
            {
                position = (j + key) % 26;
                c[i] = alphabet[position];
                printf("Ascii: %i + Key: %i.. Position = %i\n",j,key,position);

                position = 0;
                printf("Not Converted: %c\n",s[i]);
                printf("After conversion: %c\n\n",c[i]);
            }
            if(s[i] == ALPHABET[j])
            {
                position = (j + key) % 26;
                c[i] = ALPHABET[position];
                printf("Ascii: %i + Key: %i.. Position = %i\n",j,key,position);

                position = 0;
                printf("After conversion: %c\n\n",c[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("ciphertext: %s\n",c);
```

Comment: You might want to learn about [the standard character classifications functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification), like e.g. [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) and [`islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower).

Comment: `string c = s;` The type of `string` is `char *` as defined by cs50. Which means `c` just points to the same memory as `s`. It's not a copy. This illustrates why people often complain about the fact that cs50 obscures the `char *` type like this as it can lead to confusion (especially for beginners who are  the main targets of the course).

Comment: @kaylum I cannot understand why they are doing that. If you don't want to mess with pointers, there are countless other languages to choose. But if you want to learn C, you need to learn pointers. CS50 is so weird.

Comment: Seems like their explanation is to be able to do user input quickly. Well, wait with user input then. There are tons of other stuff to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
string s = get_string("plaintext: ");
string c = s;
```

to

```
string s = get_string("plaintext: ");

string c = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
strcpy(c, s);
```

That will make it work. The biggest problem here is that the course CS50 is using

```
typedef char* string;
```

to hide the complexity of pointers for new students, but in reality it just causes confusion. In order to fully understand why the above solution works, you need to understand pointers and dynamic allocation.

Comment: Isn't `get_string` some mix of stdin input and malloc?

Comment: @Lundin Probably, but OP wanted to make a copy. I don't know if there's any function for that in the cs50 library.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I tried creating a character array c and then using a for loop to put the characters from string s to char c ( array ) using integer i , but that did not work in some cipher outputs.